# How to install ZMQ in Julia 0.5 on mac

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

I want to install IJulia. But when installing the ZMQ package, I meet some errors. How can I solve them.
[The error infomation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ez6xg.png)

Comment: i guess you are working on Sierra. this is a known [issue](https://github.com/JuliaPackaging/Homebrew.jl/issues/154) of `Homebrew.jl`. My workaround is to manually download ZMQ tarball and unpack it here: `.julia/v0.5/Homebrew/deps/usr/Cellar/zeromq32/3.2.5`

Comment: How can I manually download ZMQ

Comment: you can find the URL in the error information

Comment: I had done as you said. But I get new error information. Can you tell me more details?

Comment: what's the new error information?

Comment: Warning: staticfloat/juliatranslated/libpgm-5.2.122 already installed
Warning: Already linked: /Users/apple/.julia/v0.5/Homebrew/deps/usr/Cellar/libpgm/5.2.122
Warning: staticfloat/juliadeps/zeromq32-3.2.5 already installed
Warning: Already linked: /Users/apple/.julia/v0.5/Homebrew/deps/usr/Cellar/zeromq32/3.2.5
=================================[ ERROR: ZMQ ]=================================

LoadError: Provider BinDeps.PackageManager failed to satisfy dependency zmq
while loading /Users/apple/.julia/v0.5/ZMQ/deps/build.jl, in expression starting on line 38

Comment: oh! i copied the wrong path... it should be `.julia/v0.5/Homebrew/deps/usr/Cellar/zeromq/3.2.5`, not `zeromq32`. sorry about that!